# Unable to display background-image in div

Tags: css, html, background-image, children

I basically made 960 layout with 3 divs to easily place child divs with images and text. For some reason I can't make the first background-image to display.

What am I doing wrong?

**Website concept:**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">

    <div id="left">1

        <div id="logo"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="middle">2</div>

    <div id="right">3</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { background-image:url(../bg.png);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
.wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    text-align: center;
    width: 840px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
}

#left, #middle, #right {

     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: -4px;
     width:280px;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-image:url(../logo.png));
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    }
```

Comment: which background image? the bg.png or logo.png?

Comment: Validating your CSS should be the first step in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background-image:url(../logo.png));
```

Should be...

```
background-image: url(../logo.png);
```

You may also want to use background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; and background-size: cover; to make proper use of the background of a div.

Comment: It worked but the width and height has to be manually set, is there a way to make it auto, I set width:100%; height:100% but it didn't work.

Comment: You could try to use something along the lines of {height: auto; min-height: 40px; max-height: 60px; } to allow a flexibility with some control, but different browsers will interpret differently, some will default to the max, some default to minimum. Just have to play around with it to see what looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra parenthetic for background-image under #logo in the CSS file. Change it to background-image: url(../logo.png);